# How to Replace Names in Column of a Text File, Using a Conversion Present in Another Text File With Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I did a search, and none of the other posts fit my situation. Basically, I have a long master text file that looks something like this:

```
Group1 0 100
Group2 100 200
Group3 200 300
Group4 300 400
```

Ect..

I need to replace the names in the master text file, using another text file that lists what they should be converted to.  That conversion text file looks like this:

```
Group1 Team1
Group2 Team2
Group3 Team2
Group4 Team3
```

So by using a script, I want to convert the master text file as such:

```
Team1 0 100
Team2 100 200
Team2 200 300
Team3 300 400
```

Again, these are big files, and they are not the same lengths.  Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Correct!  Thanks for the response - I was stuck last night trying to right a python script for this, but I thought I'd at least ask to see if there was a similar bash method!

Comment: You could do something similar in python, but for text processing tasks it's often quicker to write something in awk (you _could_ do it in native bash, but I'm not sure why you'd want to). How complicated you let things get before resorting to a more general-purpose language such as python is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the conversion list into an array, then use it to replace the first field in the original file:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } { $1 = a[$1] } 1' conversion.txt original.txt
```

- `NR == FNR` condition targets the first file (total line number equals file line number)
- `next` skips the rest of the script and goes to the next line
- `1` is a condition that is always true, so do the default action, `{ print }`

If you want to make sure that a replacement exists, you can add a condition `$1 in a` before the second action block.